# example of a degree 2 map from a non-elliptic curve to an elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $K$.

Can there exist a smooth projective curve $X$ over $K$ and a finite unramified map $X\rightarrow E$ of degree 2, where $X$ **does not have a $K$-rational point**?